# What happens if you do sudo passwd without specifying a user?

Tags: sudo, passwd

I wanted to change my own password (as an admin) so I did the following command:

```
sudo passwd
```

and then it prompted for a password but when I tryed to relog, my password was not changed. I'm now wondering what password did I changed since it did prompted me to enter a password but I'm not sure what password did it changed exactly.

I know that if I do `sudo passwd <MY_USER>` it works, I'm just wondering without a user what happens.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Strangely, this seems to not be documented in `man passwd`...)

If no username is specified, it defaults to the username of the user running `passwd`. Of course, as always running a program with `sudo` (without additional arguments) makes it behave as if it were run by `root`, so `sudo passwd` is equivalent to `sudo passwd root`.

Comment: Ohh I understand! Thanks alot for the information. I know I was surprised not to find it in the manual also.